# X11: how to properly support a 16-bit per pixel display

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I'm doing some xlib  programming and I have to support a 16-bit display.  As far as I know it is operating as a TrueColor  display. Is there a rule of thumb on how to allocate colors and free  them? Normally on 24 bits displays I just use raw RGB  values for my colors.

Comment: Same thing, only your colors are either 5 bits each or 5/6/5. You can know which kind you have by the R, G and B masks.

Comment: does X11 provide any convenient function to convert from RGB  to for instance 5:6:5  true color pixel  values,  or whatever my current  video  card's    subpixel  arrangement is?

Comment: X11 doesn't but there are many image libraries out there.

Comment: Meh. It wouldn't be hard to shift and mask a few bits myself.

Answer (score 1):

A TrueColor visual has a fixed colormap so all you can do is convert your rgb to a pixel value using XAllocColor() as usual.  XGetVisualInfo() will return the bitmasks you need to shift and mask the rgb values yourself if you prefer.